# Meteor - Display current time dynamically

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I need to make a time in and out app using meteor. I already created the time in function using this code:

```
Template.registerHelper('time',function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var h = d.getHours();
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    var s = d.getSeconds();
    return checkTime(h) + ":" + checkTime(m) + ":" + checkTime(s);
});
```

However, for the time out function, the current time needs to get displayed and updated in real time so the user will just have to click save. I don't know how to implement it. I can't use momentjs:moment because for some reason I can't add it to my Meteor app. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display server time on client in Meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226176/display-server-time-on-client-in-meteor)

Comment: @TristanWiley Thanks a lot!